# Multi project gradle build - java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi project build

main-module

-> api

-> pets

-> gateway

1. Configured settings.gradle in root project to include all the subprojects.
2. Included api in pets and gateway -> compile project(":api").
3. Start pets with gradlew run -> starts successfully
4. Start gateway with gradlew run -> I get below error

Execution failed for task ':api:jar'.

java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: \main-module\api\build\libs\api.jar

How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's something wrong with your build. The `api:jar` task should be considered as UP-TO-DATE at step 4 (since step 3 has already built it and nothing has changed) but it seems that it's trying to build the jar again. Most likely cause is a task input (a file) has changed

I'd guess that some of your task inputs/outputs are incorrect. Or maybe you generate a file with the current date/time in it as part of your build process?. You can try running gradle with `--info` to see why `api:jar` task is not UP-TO-DATE for step 4

See [up to date checks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks)