# gradle clean task fails with IO exception unable to delete

Tags: angular, spring-boot, gradlew

I'm posting a question that has been asked in the past because nothing I've read or tried has worked to solve my issue.  I have a multi-project Spring Boot/Angular build setup with Gradle and I'm using Gradle Wrapper version 7.6.1.  I am having an issue I did not have previously with the clean task.  The clean task for my build always fails with an IO Exception when I run "gradlew clean build" from the command line.  However, it seems to have completed the removal of the build folder the error references. The stacktrace for the error is below (not that helpful).  When I rerun "gradlew clean build" again, it fails again but this time on a different build folder for the next sub-project in the sequence.  Eventually, after rerunning 3 or 4 times, the build proceeds without issues.  I CAN, in fact, remove all build folders using typical Windows tools prior to running the build so it seems no files are locked.  I have read several articles regarding this and it seems to center around files held open by the OS (Windows in my case).  I have read articles that killing the Java VM will solve this but I'm seeing this happen immediately after a reboot when no Java processes are running.  Also, not running my IDE's (IntelliJ is mine) at the time.  Rerunning the clean build with --debug or --scan does not provide any insite.
Additional info: We use Java 17 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.4+8).  This is a recent update done last year (2022).

So why does clean seem to work properly but still causes an exception?  Note: Over the years of using Gradle, I have always dealt with the clean task failing at infrequent, random times, but this is happening every time even after a clean reboot with nothing else running that might lock a file.

I have read these POSTS:
[Multi project gradle build - java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840742/multi-project-gradle-build-java-io-ioexception-unable-to-delete-file)

https://www.eknori.de/2020-09-18/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-appclean-unable-to-delete-file/

[image: Clean task failing for Angular subproject]

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':server:clean'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file 'C:\Work\...\server\build'
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:128)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Windows and Gradle daemons. You can either stop the currently running daemons with `gradle --stop` or kill all Gradle processes from the Windows Task Manager. After that, you can either manually delete the folder or run `gradle clean` again.

To learn more about Gradle daemon management, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

P.S.: You said "*this is happening every time even after a clean reboot*", but I don't think so. Let me know if my suggestion above doesn't work for you.

Comment: I went through the info you provided in the link and tried running gradle --stop and also tried gradlew clean build --no-daemon.  Neither was successful.  Like I've said, folders can be deleted manually at the OS level and the gradlew build process also seems to remove the folders.  The error references the folder that the gradle process does in fact delete.  So odd.  Something else must be going on specific to my env and I will likely have to figure this out myself.  I do not see any other post reporting this type of behavior.